# Directive That Injects a Modal $on Event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How do I create a directive that injects a fixed position modal or a  directly underneath the element that the directive is attached to? So in the directive I would want scope.$on to trigger injecting  directly below the element.

Here's my code so far:

```
angular.module('mobileDashboardApp')
    .directive('httpErrorMessage', function (HTTPErrors) {
        return {
            template: '<div></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("hello");
                scope.$on(HTTPErrors.badRequest, function (event, args) {
                    // Inject template directly below 'element' <-- part I'm not sure how to do
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail in order for this to be answered. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi I posted my code.. I'm not sure if I'm using template in the right way. I want template injected only when I call it to be injected using the link function